# Populate drop down using php without using echo

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new to php. I am trying to populate the drop down with data from the data base. I know how to do this using echo in php. But following is the thing that I am doing and I am unable to populate the drop down with the ids in the database

```
<?php include "dbfunctions.php";

                    $result = getIds();
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id">Select ID</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="id" name="id">
                        <?php
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){      
                        ?>
                            <option><?php $row["id"];?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select><!--end form control-->
                </div><!--end form-group-->
                <?php } ?>
```

Following is the function from dbfunctions.php file that I am using to get the data from the database. This function is working fine and I am getting the data as expected.

```
function getIds(){

        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

        //you will have all the rows returned in the result
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? You're not outputting the `$row['id']`, you're just putting it there... why don't you just do `<?php echo $row['id']; ?>` in the `<option>`?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Thank you, That works just fine. But I wonder why is it working fine. Because when I tried echoing some random statement in the while loop that was not getting printed on the screen.

Comment: did you put `" "` around the `echo`

Comment: @AnujaAgarwal yes, ofcourse

Comment: @AnujaAgarwal <?php
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  
                                echo  "Hello world";
                        ?>
                            <option><?php echo $row["id"];?></option>
                        <?php } ?>

Comment: That will not show "Hello world" on the screen, because you're outputting it inside a `<select>`-statement, which only accepts `<option>`- if you look at the source code for the page, it will be there, but almost any browser will edit that out as invalid content.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie  :  spot on

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Thank you for this clarification. Thanks a lot